# Cast Java Map to IMap

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there any way to cast java.util.map(HashMap) to HazelCast IMap ?

```
Map<String, User> map = ....;
IMap<String, User> imap;
```

Thanks

Comment: Dear sir. Did you have a chance to check an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is old but here is my solution:

Add an extra dependency to the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In your unit test you will have these fields:

```
@Mock
private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

private TestHazelcastInstanceFactory hazelcastFactory = new TestHazelcastInstanceFactory();
```

And finally, in your test (assuming you are using Mockito):

```
// mock the hazelcast map
IMap<Object, Object> mockedMap = hazelcastFactory.newHazelcastInstance().getMap("doesntmatter");
mockedMap.put("some-key", someObject);

when(hazelcastInstance.getMap("testMap")).thenReturn(mockedMap);
```

Comment: why mock an instance when you can just create an actual one?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the official Hazelcast documentation:

Let's say you want to test if two members have the same size of a map.

```java
@Test
public void testTwoMemberMapSizes() {
  // start the first member
  HazelcastInstance h1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
  // get the map and put 1000 entries
  Map map1 = h1.getMap( "testmap" );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    map1.put( i, "value" + i );
  }
  // check the map size
  assertEquals( 1000, map1.size() );
  // start the second member
  HazelcastInstance h2 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
  // get the same map from the second member
  Map map2 = h2.getMap( "testmap" );
  // check the size of map2
  assertEquals( 1000, map2.size() );
  // check the size of map1 again
  assertEquals( 1000, map1.size() );
}
```

p.s. please don't write like that, use **given when then / arrange act assert**

Answer (score 2):

Mehrdad,

Hazelcast `IMap` implements `Map` and `ConcurrentMap` interfaces.
In the following case, objects `map2` and `map` will point to the same distributed object (even more, `map2` and `map` would point to the same proxy object).

`Map<Object, Object> map2 = hazelcastInstance.getMap("test");
IMap<Object, Object> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("test");`

With `Map` interface you're limited with "standard" methods. `IMap` provides extensions like submitting EntryProcessors, adding Event listeners.

I hope it does make sense.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Vik, but my problem is in unit test. the hazelcast instance is mocked. I want to add a value into mocked IMap. I need that existing value in IMap for test purposes. In mocked IMap I couldn't add any value with 'set' method. Thanks

Comment: I don't really follow. Could you share a piece of your code?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.core.IMap

Comment: IMap<String, User> iMapMocked = Mockito.mock(IMap.class); How can I add a value into this mocked IMap?

Comment: Why you do need to mock IMap? Sorry, I think I don't see a bigger picture